# Returning UDTTs to a calling C# app

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it better to return a query result through a UDTT output parameter or just let the Stored Procedure "fall through" to return the result for a calling C# app:

```
CREATE Type MyTableType AS TABLE (
    MyID INT NULL
    , MyColumn VARCHAR(10));

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcOUTPUT (
    @MyResult MyTableType OUTPUT) AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @MyResult (MyID, MyColumn)
    SELECT 1, 'The Result';
END


CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, 'The Result';
END
```

Are there any Gotcha's?
Performance for the App?
Practical limits for the result set?

Comment: I have never considered doing that but I don't know of any reason it would be problematic.

Comment: The fall-through method is nice and low tech, even an odbc connection could use it, whereas the udtt method is 'very typed' which just means mismatches will give errors. If you don't feel any preference, flip a coin :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm thinking as app programmers they might prefer strongly typed.  Needing to be deliberate with changes